# grep multiple strings for a match pattern

Tags: linux, grep

I have a directory list of  debs with different versions. My requirement is to find packages with matching version.

here is what i tried till now

```
ls debs/* | grep 1.1.16 | egrep -e 'Package1|Package2|package3'
```

This above command only gives me the o/p of Package1.

Tried all the [options](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/searching-multiple-words-string-using-grep/) from here. But none of them helps.

Comment: What you have should most likely work. Can you show the actual filenames in the `debs/` directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, [the regular warning about not parsing `ls`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). That said, assuming your files are named sanely, you could do:

```
ls debs/*1.1.16* | grep -E 'Package1|Package2|package3'
```

The only difference here is that I'm avoiding the 1st grep, which isn't needed since you can directly pass a glob pattern to `ls`. Then, instead of the deprecated `egrep`, I'm using `grep -E` which is the same thing.

However, this is essentially the same as your command. If it didn't work, then you don't have matching files:

```
$ ls debs/
1.1.16.Package3  Package1.1.1.160  Package1.1.2.16  Package2.1.1.16
$ ls debs/*1.1.16* | grep -E 'Package1|Package2|package3'
debs/Package1.1.1.160
debs/Package2.1.1.16
```

As expected, that shows the two matching files. And this is exactly what your command would have printed as well:

```
$ ls debs/* | grep 1.1.16 | egrep -e 'Package1|Package2|package3'
debs/Package1.1.1.160
debs/Package2.1.1.16
```

Note that since the `package3` is lowercase (`p` instead of `P`) in the `grep` pattern, the file `1.1.16.Package3` is not shown.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do it without paring `ls` output.

```
version=1.1.16
for package in debs/*Package1*${version}* \
               debs/*Package2*${version}* \
               debs/*package3*${version}*;
do
  action with $package;
done
```

This way shell will expand the glob and iterate through matching files. 
In case no file matches provided patterns, the script will simply skip the loop without any error.

Or try `find`:

```
version=1.1.16
find debs/ \( -name "*Package1*${version}*" -o -name "*Package2*${version}*" -o -name "*package3*${version}*" \)
```